# new date() formatting

Tags: javascript, date

I've been stuck on this for a while and need some help.
I have a date/time displayed using `"new date()"`.
It works perfect except in need it to display yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss.
It currently displays "`Thu May 31 2012 13:04:29 GMT-0500 (CDT)`".
I need it to look like "`2012 May 31 13:04:29`".

Any help would be awesome! 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) when I'm doing lots of complex and different date formatting, but this should work for you too:

```
var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

var mydate = new Date();
var curr_date = mydate.getDate();
var curr_month = mydate.getMonth();
var curr_year = mydate.getFullYear();

var mydatestr = '' + curr_year  + ' ' +
curr_month + ' ' + 
curr_date+ ' ' +
mydate.getHours() + ':' +
mydate.getMinutes() + ':' + 
mydate.getSeconds()
```

..edit..
Here's how simple it would be if you were using moment.js

```
var day = new Date()
var dayWrapper = moment(day); 
var dayString = dayWrapper.format("YYYY MMM D H:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect a response so fast! You must have answer right after I posted! Thanks for the response, but I'm still stuck. I ended up trying to use moment.js, but it's still calling new Date() only when I run my code. Later in my code when I try to use the "day" var it returns new Date() still. Sorry, I'm a noob.

Comment: the var day will always point to the Date() object, if you want the string version of the day, use the var dayString that I defined as dayWrapper.format("your-format-here");

Answer (score 1):

Using standard JavaScript, you have to rely on what the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) gives you:

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
now = new Date(),
formatted = now.getFullYear() + ' ' + months[now.getMonth()] + ' ' + 
    now.getDate() + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + 
    now.getSeconds();
```

You may need to pad your single digits, but that's readers exercise :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime visitDate = DateTime.Parse("Thu May 31 2012 13:04:29");
        Label1.Text = visitDate.ToString("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

here are couple of links that may help you

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/javascript_date_and_time.php3

or using pure javascript you can do this

```
var month=new Array();
month[0]="January";
month[1]="February";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="August";
month[8]="September";
month[9]="October";
month[10]="November";
month[11]="December";

var d = new Date();
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var nmonth=month[d.getMonth()];
var nyear = d.getFullYear(); 
var nday = d.getDate();
var nhours = d.getHours()
var nminutes = d.getMinutes();
var nseconds=d.getSeconds();

var wholesyting=nyear+" "+nmonth+" "+nday+" "+nhours+":"+nminutes+":"+nseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can execute the following on your date's string representation:

```
varname.replace(/^\S+\s(\S+\s\S+\s)(\S+\s)(\S+)\s.*$/, "$2$1$3");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss");
Date dated = format.parse(format.format(new Date()));
```